# How disable specific layout folder from res/ programmitcaly?

Tags: android-layout

In my app is many of layouts and I want to disallow to use a specific layout in some cases. But I don't want to delete this layout folder from my app. 
Is there any possibility?

I want to do from Java source level. e.g. if user click a button than application start not using layouts form specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

Different layout is for to support different screen size of the device.

You have to put some code in the manifest file as i guess.

See :[this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)

Where you can come to know about what you can do if you dont want to access/support to some specific layout/Screen size.